# Force sign up with the Google Identity Toolkit on iOS

Tags: ios, google-identity-toolkit

Dear GIT team and Stackoverflowers,

I'm using the Google Identity Toolkit in my iOS app and most of it is pretty cool.

I have a question regarding the use of gmail email addresses (everything that's considered a gmail address). Is it possible to force the GIT SDK to create a new account instead of linking with a existing gmail account?

For instance, if I were to try to sign in into my iOS app using my gmail email address, is it possible to indicate to GIT that it should NOT redirect to the Google sign in page, but rather to create a new account?

We've found that this process is a bit confusing for some users and would like to find a way to possibly change the flow a bit.

Appreciate any feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to use the Rollout Percentage feature in the Identity Toolkit configuration page of Google Developers Console. If you set the rollout percentage to 0, users with @gmail.com will be treated as password accounts. If the percentage is set to 100, all users with @gmail will sign in

Regarding the question "create a new account instead of linking with a existing gmail account?", Google Identity Toolkit creates an account for *your* application, by copying the email address, name and photo_url from the user's account at Google. These are two separated accounts.

Comment: I'll update the question once we have tried out your proposal. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: This seems to work, but only for emails that have never been used with GIT - which basically makes a lot of sense. 

Thanks a lot for the tip! :)

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not using Gitkit in an iOS app, you should be able to uncheck Google as an authentication option by going to the developers console for the project and clicking APIs > Enabled APIs > Identity Toolkit API > Settings.

Comment: Hmm, good idea. We could give that a try. 

Although, disabling Google client-side was fruitless, hopefully this could give better results! :)